# Diff in calendar days with PHP Carbon

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I want to get difference in calendar days. I want to spot dates that correspond to today, yesterday and tomorrow with relative numbers (0, -1, 1).

Here are some basic tests:

```
\Carbon\Carbon::now() // Out: 2017-08-08 09:16 ...

// diffInDays()

\Carbon\Carbon::now()->diffInDays(\Carbon\Carbon::now()->addHour(1)) // output: 0
\Carbon\Carbon::now()->diffInDays(\Carbon\Carbon::now()->tomorrow()) // output: 0
\Carbon\Carbon::now()->diffInDays(\Carbon\Carbon::now()->addHour(23)) // output: 0
\Carbon\Carbon::now()->diffInDays(\Carbon\Carbon::now()->addHour(25)) // output: 1


// diffInWeekDays()

\Carbon\Carbon::now()->diffInWeekDays(\Carbon\Carbon::now()->addHour(1)) // output: 1
\Carbon\Carbon::now()->diffInWeekDays(\Carbon\Carbon::now()->tomorrow()) // output: 1
\Carbon\Carbon::now()->diffInWeekDays(\Carbon\Carbon::now()->addHour(23)) // output: 1
\Carbon\Carbon::now()->diffInWeekDays(\Carbon\Carbon::now()->addHour(25)) // output: 2
```

Both methods seem to count days by periods of 24 hrs. What I would like to get with "someMethod":

```
\Carbon\Carbon::now()->someMethod(\Carbon\Carbon::now()->addHour(1)) // output: 0
\Carbon\Carbon::now()->someMethod(\Carbon\Carbon::now()->tomorrow()) // output: 1
\Carbon\Carbon::now()->someMethod(\Carbon\Carbon::now()->addHour(23)) // output: 1
\Carbon\Carbon::now()->someMethod(\Carbon\Carbon::now()->addHour(25)) // output: 1
```

Is there any way to get my needed output within Carbon?

I've created a related issue in the Carbon repository here: https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/issues/990

Any comment or help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Since the `diffInDays()` is based on 24hours, you can trick by using `startOfDay()` method

```
\Carbon\Carbon::now()->startOfDay()->diffInDays(\Carbon\Carbon::now()->addHours(23)->startOfDay(), false)
```

Note the `false` parameter to get the negative number of days

Comment: Oh my! I found the same solution and posted it in Github. It works fine! For me at least it covers my needings. I'm starting to suspect that there isn't any native method in Carbon to cover this...

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:

```
$date = <some_date>;

\Carbon\Carbon::now()->startOfDay()->diffInDays($date, false);
```